# Calculus of an n-dimensional integral with Mathematica

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Is possible to evaluate the integral
$\int_0^1 dx_1\int_0^{1-x_1} dx_2\int_0^{1-x_2} dx_3\cdots \int_0^{1-x_{n-1}} dx_n$ with Mathematica?

Comment: If n is some fixed positive integer, like 6, then perhaps `Integrate[1,Sequence@@Table[{a[j],0,If[j==1,1,1-a[j-1]]},{j,1,6}]]`  Change `Integrate` to something like `q` and evaluate to inspect what arguments will be passed to `Integrate`

Comment: I think it's a shame that this question was closed. To me the notation is unambiguous, and it can be formalised [like this][1]. I solve in Mathematica as follows:  `With[{n = 6}, #[x] & /@ NestList[Function[{x}, Integrate[#[y], {y, 0, 1 - x}]]] &, 1 &, n] // Together`  [1]: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4415715/a-polynomial-sequence-by-iterated-integration

Answer (score 6):

Take the fine results of @Bill

```
Table[Integrate[1, 
  Sequence @@ 
   Table[{a[j], 0, If[j == 1, 1, 1 - a[j - 1]]}, {j, 1, n}]], {n, 1, 
  8}]
```

and @bmf

```
ff[xx_] := 
  Integrate[1, 
   Sequence @@ 
    Table[{gg[j], 0, If[j == 1, 1, 1 - gg[j - 1]]}, {j, 1, xx}]];Table[ff[n], {n, 1, 8}]
```

to get list

```
{1, 1/2, 1/3, 5/24, 2/15, 61/720, 17/315, 277/8064}
```

Insert that list at serach site for integer sequences https://oeis.org/search?q=3,5,9,1,4,0,9,1&sort=&language=english&go=Search

You see, list is a series development of Sec and Tan

```
f[n_] = SeriesCoefficient[Sec[x] + Tan[x], {x, 0, n}, 
  Assumptions -> n > 0 && Element[n, Integers]]

(*   Piecewise[{{(I^n*EulerE[n])/n!, 
    Mod[n, 2] == 0}}, 
  (I*(2*I)^n*(-1 + (-1)^n)*
    (-1 + 2^(1 + n))*
    BernoulliB[1 + n])/(1 + n)!]   *)

Table[f[n], {n, 1, 8}]

(*   {1, 1/2, 1/3, 5/24, 2/15, 61/720, 17/315, 277/8064}   *)
```

Comment: (+1) from me. I cannot believe I forgot to employ the [`FindSequenceFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindSequenceFunction.html) and/or OEIS. Wonderful stuff!!!

Comment: @bmf I do not understand what's  so wonderful, it's just guessing. Now not only students google even simplest integrals, I have seen profs doing this.

Comment: @yarchik so, the fact that I left a polite comment has to be justified? I do not understand. Did I do anything against the rules or something?

Comment: @bmf Nothing to be justified. You left a polite comment, I expressed my opinion on your comment and on the above solution, hopefully polite too. No downvotes. We simply have different opinions how math should be done, especially on a problem that can be easily solved rigorously. I think it is normal, isn't it?

Comment: @yarchik yes, of course. I was not offended and did not mean to be cheeky. My question was honest, i.e if it is bad to leave comments like these. In any case, as you say it's just a difference of approaches on a given maths problem, which I think is good in any situation as you also pointed out :-)

Answer (score 3):

I agree that you should have added clarification, but I don't agree with zero help to a newcomer.

I am hoping that the following will at least get you started.

---

- In case you want to multiply $n$ integrals with $1$ as integrand and variable limits.

Consider

```
ff[xx_] := 
 With[{n = xx}, 
    Integrate[Product[1, {k, 0, n}], 
     Sequence @@ Table[{x[k], 0, 1 - x[k - 1]}, {k, n, 1, -1}]]] /. 
   x[0] -> 0 // Expand
```

Check for $n=3$

```
ff[3]

1 - x[1] - x[2] + x[1] x[2]
```

And explicitly

```
Integrate[1, {x1, 0, 1}] Integrate[1, {x[2], 0, 1 - x[1]}] Integrate[
   1, {x[3], 0, 1 - x[2]}] // Expand

1 - x[1] - x[2] + x[1] x[2]
```

---

- In case you want to use previous in the next and so on.

Consider

```
ff[xx_] := 
 Integrate[1, 
  Sequence @@ 
   Table[{gg[j], 0, If[j == 1, 1, 1 - gg[j - 1]]}, {j, 1, xx}]]
```

Check for $n=3$

```
ff[3]

1/3
```

and explicitly you get

```
Integrate[
 Integrate[
  Integrate[1, {x[3], 0, 1 - x[2]}], {x[2], 0, 1 - x[1]}], {x[1], 0, 
  1}]

1/3
```

Comment: Surely `Product[1, {k, 0, n}]` is equal to `1`?

Comment: @Joe it seems [`so`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNSD7.png). Did you try the code and it fails?

Comment: @Joe because on my machine I get [`the right results`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdF5p.png)

Comment: Oh no I didn't run the code, it just seemed strange to me to put in `Product[1, {k, 0, n}]` instead of `1`

Comment: @Joe ok I see. I just thought you run into problems and it seemed weird. Thanks for the comment :-)

Comment: @Joe I managed to see your comment, so please allow me to say that since there is an inherent ambiguity in the OP I decided to address both the physics conventions and the maths conventions. In other words, the way the OP is phrased can be understood as $n$-integrations of $1$ multiplying themselves (maths convention) **OR** a nested integration (physics convention). I have addressed both and made it very clear which is which. Please take a moment to run the code and convince yourself. Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: As far as I'm aware it's not down to convention. If you have $\int d^2x f(x_1,x_2)$, then you either do $\int dx_1 \int dx_2 f(x_1,x_2)$, or you can integrate in the other order (doing $\int dx_1$ first). It's only in the case that $f(x_1,x_2)=g(x_1)h(x_2)$ that the nested integrals become a product of integrals. In the OP, they are not a product because the limits depend on $x_i$, so the integrand is $f(x_1,...,x_n)=1$. It is true that $1=1^n$, but writing $f=1^n$ in this case indicated to me a potential misunderstanding about multiple integration. I'm sure your code is correct

Comment: @Joe please, read carefully the OP and my reply. The simplest case is written as: $\int^1_0 dx_1 \int^{1-x_1}_0 dx_2$. I can interpret this as: $\left( \int^1_0 dx_1 \right) \left( \int^{1-x_1}_0 dx_2 \right)$ hence the command would be `Integrate[1, {x1, 0, 1}] Integrate[1, {x2, 0, 1 - x1}]` that yields `1 - x1` **OR** $\left(\int^1_0 dx_1 \left( \int^{1-x_1}_0 dx_2 \right)\right)$ which you code as `Integrate[Integrate[1, {x2, 0, 1 - x1}], {x1, 0, 1}]` and gives `1/2`. As there was no clarification by the author of the OP, I opted for demonstrating both distinctly. Thanks for your comments!

Comment: @Joe there's no context disallowing the multiplication in the way that the question was posed from my point of view.

Comment: @Joe it's also possible that the sloppy high-energy notation is making me see ghosts everywhere, even if there are none. That might also be the case :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135101/discussion-between-joe-and-bmf).

Answer (score 3):

We set `x[0]==0` and use `RegionMeasure`.

```
int[k_] := 
  ImplicitRegion[
    Join[{x[0] == 0}, Table[0 <= x[n] <= 1 - x[n - 1], {n, 1, k}]], 
    Evaluate@Table[x[n], {n, 0, k}]] // RegionMeasure;
int /@ Range[9]
```

> `{1, 1/2, 1/3, 5/24, 2/15, 61/720, 17/315, 277/8064, 62/2835}`

Comment: Very cool use of `ImplicitRegion` and `IntegrationMeasure`!!!!